# Is it possible to do nested search in jsonpath-ng?

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

Source "mapping.json":

```
{
  "result": {
    "src_color": "test_rule_2"
  },
  "rules": {
    "color_degree": {
      "test_rule_1": {
        "color": 1
      },
      "test_rule_2": {
        "color": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So it works perfectly:

```
with open("mapping.json", 'r') as json_file:
    mapping = json.load(json_file)

expression = parse('$.rules.color_degree.test_rule_2.color')
match = expression.find(mapping)

if match:
    pprint(match[0].value)
```

but in the path "test_rule_2" I need to replace with the value from result->src_color

How to properly describe something like this:

```
expression = parse('$.rules.color_degree.($.result.src_color.value).color')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it can be done, but you need two steps:

```
#first: get the variable:
src_expression = parse('$.result.src_color')
src_match = src_expression.find(mapping)

#second: get the target
expression = parse(f'$.rules.color_degree.{src_match[0].value}.color')
match = expression.find(mapping)
if match:
    print(match[0].value)
```

Output is `2`.

EDIT:

I don't know why someone would want to do it in one step, but it's possible:

```
parse(f'$.rules.color_degree.{parse("$.result.src_color").find(mapping)[0].value}.color').find(mapping)[0].value
```

Same output.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but in my task I need to get the result in one step if possible

Comment: my task is to get these mapping rules from the server as a string, your option really does in one step, but in my task it is not applicable. thank you anyway, I will change the approach to solving the problem

Comment: how to do that using xquery?

Comment: @Aviator It be done, probably; you should post it as a separate question.